# R Error: Non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, return

I wrote a function that would calculate two different variables. I want to return both the variables combining in a prompt sentence however it tells me that I am making an error.

I tried to use as.character on both of the rates but it doesn't work.

```r
return("Of " + class + " class" + rate2 + " % of women and children survived and " + rate1 + " % of men survived.")
```

I expect the output to be something like "Of 1st class, 80% of women and children survived and 10% of men survived.

Answer (score 1):

Use `paste` here:

```
return(paste0("Of ", class, " class", rate2, " % of women and children survived and ", rate1, " % of men survived."))
```

Unlike several other programming languages (such as Java, C#, and Python), R does *not* overload the `+` operator to allow for string concatenation.  The `paste()` function is the base R way of achieving what you are trying to do.

Comment: It still sent me the same error after return(paste(...)).

Comment: @HoaNgocQuynhLe Sorry, I didn't test my code when answering, it should work now.

Comment: [1] "Of c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4) class3 % of women and children survived and 97 % of men survived."     
[2] "Of c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2) class3 % of women and children survived and 97 % of men survived."     
[3] "Of c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2) class3 % of women and children survived and 97 % of men survived."     
[4] "Of c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2) class3 % of women and children survived and 97 % of men survived."     
[5] "Of c(0, 0, 670, 3, 0, 0, 192, 20) class3 % of women and children survived and 97 % of men survived."